# Comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+7}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+7}$

My textbook did the limit comparison test to do this but cant you just do this using direct comparison test?

What I did

For $n \geq 1, \forall n \in \mathbb N$, $a_n = \frac{1}{2n+7} \leq \frac{1}{n} = b_n$

Since $$0 < a_n \leq b_n, \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

Direct comparison test applies

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$. Since this is a p-series with magnitude one we know that $\sum b_n$ diverges. Therefore by the direct comparison test $\sum a_n$ diverges as well.

Usually my textbook does the easiest way so I don't know.

Comment: What did your textbook do?

Comment: Same $b_n$ but they used limit comparison to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ = # $\in (0, \infty)$. Why is this neccesary?

Comment: Arguably both are of the same difficulty, though the limit comparison test has wider application -- the idea of considering how a function/sequence behaves in the "long run" is important. Here, the intuition is to realize $1/(2n+7)$ basically grows like $1/n$ -- no need or any bounding.

Comment: So both solutions are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use direct Comparison Test.

For all $n\geq 1$, we get
$$\frac{1}{2n+\color\red 7}\geq\frac{1}{2n+\color\red{7n}}=\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{n}.$$
Since the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$$ is a divergent series, it follows from the Comparison Test that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+7}$$ is also divergent.

Comment: Thx I really like this way

Answer (score 1):

If you have got $b_{n} \leq a_{n}$, then $\sum_{n}b_{n}$ divergent implies $\sum_{n}a_{n}$ diverges. But you have got $b_{n} \geq a_{n}$; so there is no guarantee in this case. To apply comparison test, you have to seek another sequence $c_{n}$ ensuring that $a_{n} \geq c_{n}$ and that $\sum_{n}c_{n}$ diverges.

However, the limit comparison test can get you what you want immediately. Recall that the theorem states that if $a_{n},b_{n} \geq 0$ for all integers $n > 0$ and if $\lim_{n}a_{n}/b_{n}  > 0$ then either $\sum_{n}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n}b_{n}$ both converges or both diverges. Note that
$$
\frac{1}{2n+7} \times n \to \frac{1}{2} > 0.
$$

Comment: Oh so it doesnt work the same way as convergence? I get it, thank you.

Comment: Yeah by looking at a proof of comparison test you will see immediately. If instead $\sum_{n}b_{n}$ converges then $a_{n} \geq b_{n}$ implies $\sum_{n}a_{n}$ converges.